# Bootstrap Navbar align few links to right (non collapsible)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align the contact info on the right side of navbar but I do not want it to collapse on mobile phone resolution.

Would be perfect if it could realign in the center on mobile phones.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

```html
<div class="navbar navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #fff">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Pagrindinis</a>
                    <li><a href="">Galerija</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">vytas.velick@gmail.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="tel:525251624">52521624</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">FACEBOOK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One option might be to go with media queries, and specify the style based on resolution, have you tried that?

Comment: I dont know if You saw picture. But my "contacts links" are not in the same line with other pages links.

Comment: And... do you want them in the same line? I don't understand.